# navigation issue between viewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller, pushviewcontroller

After pushing a viewcontroller, when I want to pop it back my application is crashing.

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
if (viewControllers.count>0) {
    [[self navigationController]  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the controller I'm pushing, has uiwebview and for the requirement I m doing
[twebView stopLoading];

I'm clueless. anyone please give me a good working suggestion.
and is there any easy way to pushviewcontroller from right to left??

Comment: on what exactly line it is crashes? and what is error message on crash?

Comment: A viewcontroller pushed is normally popped by calling `[self.navigationcontroller popViewControllerAnimated:]` without extra code like the code in yours. I guess there is anything wrong in other places. Let me show a crash message.

Comment: @KyokookHwang yeah dats what it should behave. n I tried [self.navigationcontroller popViewControllerAnimated:] first n den stratted trying everything else. Its not that everytime its crashing but if I'm stoploading the webview, its not popping the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure if the following link is useful or not. check the like out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651108/579236

Answer (score 1):

First `alloc` your  array first. Refer following code:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]init];
viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

NSLog(@"Controllers = %@",viewControllers);

if (viewControllers.count>0) {
    [[self navigationController]  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And also check log of controllers as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[OldViewController class]])
        {
            //Do not forget to import AnOldViewController.h

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
```